# A one-word synonym of "to give meaning to"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a verb whose definition is "to give/assign meaning to", "to define a function of", "to invent a use/meaning for" or something close. This might be a little vague, but I hope I can at least get some guesses or stabs at it.

On a similar note, are there web searches that allow for finding words given their meanings?

Comment: I am having a little trouble figuring out what you are asking. Can you provide a few example sentences with [blank] for the word you want?

Comment: [OneLook Reverse Dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)

Comment: @MrHen Not sure if I got it right, not being NSE, but I think the OP's asking about a one-word term that can be used as a verb and denotes the act of **making something meaningful**. E.g. "*I become a father and that **gave meaning to** my existence.*". The best suggestion I have to offer on that is *to meanigfulize* but it's not that goody and definitely maddy-uppy.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Urban Dictionary: [Semanticate](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Semanticate#)

> v. tr. (from the adj. semantic); the intended meaning (implicit or explicit) of an individual’s communication; that which is trying to be communicated by an individual.
>
> > When I speak of ‘freedom’ I do not mean the bland and passive ‘freedom from’ commitment or responsibility that is too often semanticated.

The word is also well defined and used in **Computer Science**.

From the [Semantic Web](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/User_talk:Hillgentleman): "... reads the first paragraph(,) takes the first sentence, and semanticate(s) it as the principal attribute ..."

[SVN Code](http://svn.codehaus.org/setpoint/setpoint/trunk/semanticator/Semanticator.cs)

```
namespace semanticator {
public class Semanticator {
    private AssemblyDefinition semanticatedFile;
public void semanticate(string fileName) {
        string ontologyString = sourceCodeSemantics(fileName);
        addOntologyToAssembly(fileName, ontologyString);
```

Comment: Gah! That's not a word!

Comment: Urban Dictionary should really be flagged: while it has an undeniable rugged appeal, enquirers using it as a source for genuine English are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5):

I can only think of:

> Vindicate
>
> Justify
>
> Legitimize

Comment: When used in this context, you might also use 'validate'.

Answer (score 5):

The parameters are several, but words that fit one or another of them that come to mind: imbue, inscribe, coin, imprint, mark.

No need to over-think it, though: "name" and "define" work perfectly well.

Answer (score 4):

to signify;
to ascribe meaning

Answer (score 3):

A few options:

- coin — "He coined a phrase."
- define
- determine
- specify
- assign
- establish
- ascertain
- discover

Answer (score 2):

"add significance to"
"give import to"
"disambiguate"

Or just "clarify"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but does *institute* work?

Answer (score 0):

From Dictionary.com:

**[denote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/denote)**

de·note
[dih-noht]

> 1.to be a mark or sign of; indicate: A fever often denotes an infection.
>     2. to be a name or designation for; mean.
>     3. to represent by a symbol; stand as a symbol for.